# Why does upright text orientation not work in Safari or Edge?

Tags: css

From what I can tell, `text-orientation:upright` has no effect in either Safari or Edge, though it works fine in Chrome and Firefox. I can find no mention of this issue anywhere at all. The only caveat listed on https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-text-orientation is that Safari requires the -webkit- prefix but I've provided that and it still doesn't work. Here's a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/tn3bdf52/

My only access to Safari is on an iPad but in Edge's dev tools the property has a red underline as though it's invalid. The `writing-mode:vertical-lr` property has a black line-through like it's being overridden but IDK by what. It's still working. I tried changing the value to `tb-lr` but it made no difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did a little mistake with the prefix **-webkit-**. -webkit-text-orientation is the correct rule tested on Mac with Safari. Please try.

P.S. In Microsoft Edge v.80.0.361 text-orientation is also works

```css
ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  writing-mode: vertical-lr;
  -webkit-text-orientation: upright;
  text-orientation: upright;
}

li {
  padding: 1em .5em;
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
  <ul class="">
    <li class="first"><a href="/variis/opa">Opa</a></li>
    <li><a href="/variis/fire-tower">Fire Tower</a></li>
    <li class="last"><a href="/variis/dandelion-on-the-wind">Dandelion on the Wind</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Ah, typical of me. And it looks like my version of Edge is 44, even tho Windows says I'm all up to date, so I guess that's my problem there. Sorry. Another stupid question. I'll delete it.

Comment: Looks like I can't delete it.